# Returning RSS from React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rss

I'm not sure how to resolve this.  I get syntax errors in WebStorm when I try to return the first line.

```
const Feed = Component({
    render() {
        return (
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <rss version="2.0">
                    <channel>
                        <title>Test</title>
                        <link>test</link>
                        <description>test</description>
                        <item>
                            <title>test</title>
                            <link>test</link>
                            <guid>test</guid>
                            <pubDate>Tues, 23 Aug 2016 10:00:00 CDT</pubDate>
                            <description>test</description>
                        </item>
                    </channel>
                </rss>
        );
    }
})

export default Feed
```

For something React doesn't like the syntax `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` because it doesn't recognize what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, React doesn't recognize `xml`. So, you need to convert your xml to string and put it under `<pre>` tag to preserve the indents.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Pranesh456/qt2bp9oe/3/

Comment: I'm not trying to parse data out of XML.  I'm trying to generate a page that is an RSS feed, something like this: https://egghead.io/feed

Comment: I guess I don't see how converting this to json would help me

Comment: You need to parse the data out of the `xml` first and use the parsed data (`JSON`) to generate a page using `React`

Comment: I don't want React to process it as jsx, I just want react to spit out the literal xml

Comment: hehe I was actually just trying the same thing at the same time, but didn't try <pre>

Comment: That's called `Template literals`. You can refer the same here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: I also noticed you treated it as JS by surrounding it with  {}.  It's just confusing to me how that works with the jsx in this particular case because I don't have any js code in there but still had to use {}

Comment: any idea how to keep the indentation after it renders?

Comment: `{}` is used to include dynamic contents into the HTML. 
For Example: `'<div>'+ myName + '</div>'` can be written as `<div>{myName}</div>`

Comment: thanks.  Also probably need to beautify it somehow too to keep indentation. https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-beautify

Comment: Yea I've used {} before just not for string templates but I guess string templates is a JS function so it'll treat that string in the {} as JS which means ` will render it as a template

Comment: Beautifying the `<xml>` should help!